# Use image to fill in arc in canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I am totally new to canvas and trying a project in which I need to make small balls move around with their background as images. Following code is what I am trying right now.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(
  this.pos[0], this.pos[1], this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true
);
let tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
let ballbackground = new Image();
if (this.color === "green") {
    ballbackground.src = "https://s26.postimg.cc/fl2vwj1mh/greenball.png";
    }
else if (this.color === "yellow") {
    ballbackground.src = "https://s26.postimg.cc/if61a18yh/yellowball.png";
    }
else if (this.color === "blue") {
    ballbackground.src = "https://s26.postimg.cc/xb4khn7ih/blueball.jpg";
    }
tempCanvas.width = 50;
tempCanvas.height = 50;
tCtx.drawImage(ballbackground,0,0,ballbackground.width, ballbackground.height,0,0,50,50);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, "repeat");
```

And for moving those balls I do as follows:

```
const velocityScale = timeDelta / NORMAL_FRAME_TIME_DELTA,
    offsetX = this.vel[0] * velocityScale * this.speed,
    offsetY = this.vel[1] * velocityScale * this.speed;
    this.pos = [this.pos[0] + offsetX, this.pos[1] + offsetY];
```

However, the problem is when objects move they seem like sliding over background image like so:

[image: click here for image]

If I try "no-repeat" with createPattern, the balls won't display at all.

What I want is those balls with background images moving on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the balls by using the canvas transform?

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

const pattern = createPattern(ctx);

function drawCircleByPosition(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawCircleByTransform(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;  
  drawCircleByPosition(ctx, 90, 75 + Math.sin(time) * 50);
  drawCircleByTransform(ctx, 210, 75 + Math.sin(time) * 50);
 
  requestAnimationFrame(render); 
}
requestAnimationFrame(render); 

function createPattern(ctx) {
  const tCtx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  tCtx.canvas.width = 50;
  tCtx.canvas.height = 50;
  tCtx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  tCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
  for (let x = 0; x < 50; x += 20) {
    tCtx.fillStyle = "red";
    tCtx.fillRect(x, 0, 10, 50);
    tCtx.fillStyle = "blue";
    tCtx.fillRect(0, x, 50, 10);
  }
  return ctx.createPattern(tCtx.canvas, "repeat");
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

note that rather than call `save` and `restore` you can also just set the transform with [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) which is probably faster since save and restore saves all state (fillStyle, strokeStyle, font, globalCompositeOperation, lineWidth, etc...).

You can either pass in your own matrix. Example

```
 ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);  // for translation
```

and/or you can reset it to the default whenever and then use the standard transform manipulation functions

```
 ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // the default
 ctx.translate(x, y);
```

or whatever combination of things you want to do.

Comment: It does make sense, thanks a lot, however now that it is translated to the center of the ball the image would only appear in the bottom right of the ball with ```no-repeat``` and with ```repeat``` it would just clone itself in all other three quadrants of the circle instead of showing up as a whole.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, I translated the starting point once again before putting pattern on the temporary canvas, thanks again for your help.